# How do you get authenticated with steam in a websocket connection?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm trying to automate interaction with a website that uses websockets. In theory all I need to do is get authenticated with steam and then send 1 piece of data, but I'm having trouble getting authenticated.
I manage to get the connection set up. But after I send my steam token (replicating what I see happens in the devtools of my browser), it replies that I am not logged in.

Below is the code I currently have. Locally it doesn't work at all. But on repl.it (an online editor) it has the effect it's supposed to have but the websocket still replies that I am not logged in.

The code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import time
import sys

token = "YOUR_STEAM_TOKEN_HERE"

adress = 'wss://eu.pug.champ.gg/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket'
authtemplate = '42["authenticate",{{"token":{0}}}]'
rolesupdatetemplate = '42["updateAvailability",{0}]'

async def add(roles):
  async with websockets.connect(adress) as websocket:
    await websocket.send(authtemplate.format(token))

    roles_string = json.dumps(roles)
    await websocket.send(rolesupdatetemplate.format(roles_string))


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(add({'roles': ['roamer', 'pocket'], 'captain': False})
```

)

Some extra info:
When on the site normally, the websocket I'm connected to according to the developer tools has an extra argument compared to the one I use in my code. The extra argument being: sid=....
However, adding this manually gives me error code 400.

I've tried looking up how to do this but I can't find the answer anywhere. Do I need to send cookies?
Do I need to get the websocket address in another way rather than manually?
What am I missing?